# How to set proper permissions for statefulsets resource in Kubernete?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, minishift, instana

I am running a Instana Agent on minishift. I see these logs:

```
 oc logs -f pod/instana-agent-dg5lt
```

> 2020-05-26T03:10:58.763+00:00 | WARN  | nstana-sensor-scheduler-thread-1 | Kubernetes       | com.instana.sensor-kubernetes - 1.2.106 | Instana agent does not have permission to watch for statefulsets changes. Kubernetes sensor will not work properly without this permission. Please ensure proper permissions for `statefulsets` resource.

How to set proper permissions for statefulsets resource in Kubernete?

**edit**

I used 2 yaml files. I used this yaml file to install operator ditto as is without any change: https://github.com/instana/instana-agent-operator/releases/latest/download/instana-agent-operator.yaml

And I used this custom resource yaml file https://github.com/instana/instana-agent-operator/blob/master/deploy/instana-agent.customresource.yaml with just two changes: I added `size: 1` under spec key and replaced `replace-me` with proper agent key.

**edit2**

I used `oc api-resources` as that's how I created the project and deployed definition files. Result can be found here -> https://pastebin.com/A6zRRReS

Comment: share the yaml of instana agent. How did you install the agent?

Comment: I just included it in the question.

Comment: What is the version of your kubernetes cluster? Is it pretty old? share output of kubectl api-resources

Comment: I updated it under edit2.

Comment: Your linked file "instana-agent-operator.yaml" contains the necessary `ClusterRole` and `ClusterRoleBinding`, so in theory the `instana-agent-operator` ServiceAccount should have the permissions. Can you add the output for `oc get ServiceAccount, Deployment -n instana-agent -o yaml`, `oc get ClusterRoleBinding instana-agent-operator` and `oc get ClusterRole instana-agent-operator -n instana-agent`? This should show us if the resources were applied correctly.

Comment: @Simon I will do that in a bit. However, I see that you answer both Openshift questions and Kubernetes questions. Do you recommend any book to read to get solid understanding of both or either? And, what should I learn first?

Comment: @Faraz OpenShift is the Red Hat distribution of Kubernetes, so OpenShift IS Kubernetes. So any good Kubernetes book / reading will do, however I found the Red Hat Learnings to be quite good: https://learn.openshift.com